# Failed to lookup view "/landing.ejs" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm working in Cloud9 and when trying to run the application i'm greeted with the error failed to lookup view "/landing.ejs" in views directory: 
Thus far I have:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();



app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("/landing.ejs");
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server is running");
})
```

My file tree is structed as such App > v1 > app.js package.json views > landing.ejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first,you have to set default view files path `app.set('views', __dirname + '/view_files_folder_path');` after the line `var app = express();` .
Then modify this `res.render("/landing.ejs");` to `res.render("landing.ejs");` 
Hope this will work :)

Comment: This caused me to realize I shouldn't be putting the "/" before landing.ejs and that caused the file to work correctly. I was stuck on this for over an hour before I called it a night, thank you! I am curious, what does the app.set('views', __dirname + '/view_files_folder_path'); do specifically? And should I change it to be app.set('views', __dirname + '/view_landing');?

Comment: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/view_landing');` it will set a default view file location.For example if you try to render `res.render("landing.ejs");` it will automatically look upon in the location of `..../folder/view_landing/landing.ejs`